# Alternative Ganglia interfaces?

Tags: metrics, ganglia, gmond, gmetad

I'm evaluating various metric collection systems and appreciate just about everything in Ganglia, except for the less than clean interface. Does anyone know of alternative Ganglia interfaces or additions to the interface that allow custom grouping of hosts a la Cacti's left pane tree view?

Could really use some help with this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ganglia web frontend 2.0 was just announced at [Velocity](http://velocityconf.com/velocity2011):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganglia/files/gweb/2.0.0/

http://vuksan.com/blog/2010/12/10/rethinking-ganglia-web-ui/

That's a cleaner interface with some new features.